# Self-replicating Linux

Tags: linux, replication

Looking for a project that aims at creating a self-replicating Linux distro, i.e. a distro that when connected to other devices, attempts to replicate itself on those devices. Is there such a thing?

Comment: isn't that a virus ?

Comment: Would all artificial life-forms be considered viruses?

Answer (score 2):

These projects obviously does not exist.
If these would exist - they would already took over the world by installing linux on every player, keyboard, router, and all humans too.

From the serious side, this would be illegal.

Comment: Stuxnet anyone?

Comment: Illegal? Show me the law.

Comment: If it's not illegal in your locality, it's at least legally questionable, which the lawyers would have a field day with.

Comment: @infojunkie - well in the UK it would fall foul of the Computer Misuse Act, for a start.